# 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' setting up a context menu in a control template

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, controltemplate

I am getting this error and I really have no idea how to solve it no matter how much I google!

This is the style defined in my Theme.xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="RightClickCopyPasteLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Opened="OnMenuOpened">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="CopyMenuItem" Click="OnCopyEvent" InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" Header="Copy" IsEnabled="{Binding CanExecuteCopy}">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="PasteMenuItem" Click="OnPasteEvent" InputGestureText="Ctrl+P" Header="Paste" IsEnabled="{Binding CanExecutePaste}">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ContextMenu>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is my control. There is very little to say really. I think it should work. I want to create a template for a right click context menu that I can apply to labels. I am not sure where I am going wrong?

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataForgeEditor.Controls.Expander"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                     xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/DataForgeTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Expander Name="ExpanderControl" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    <Expander.Header>
        <Label Name="ExpanderLabel" Style="{StaticResource RightClickCopyPasteLabel}" />
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

**EDIT:**

I have just tried this a very basic style.. this doesn't even work!

```
<Style x:Key="TestLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Border Background="AntiqueWhite"></Border>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What is the inner `Exception`?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be one, I have tried everything

Comment: try
   {
    InitializeComponent();
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex)
   {
    ErrorConsole.Instance.LogError(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message);
   }


Doesn't work

Comment: When the `Exception` occurs, click *View Details* in the popup dialog and then look in the *Inner `Exception`* property in the `Exception` dialog that opens.

Comment: @Asheh - If you add the resource directly under UserControl resources (after getting rid of resource dictionary) does that work for you?

Comment: There is no "view details":

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '11'.

Comment: Ahh the weekend has refreshed me. OK If i continue over the exception I finally get more output!

'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '11'.
'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'IsMouseOver'.